# HAProxy: When is server_id 0?

Tags: haproxy

I've been working with HAProxy to dynamically add/remove a lot of servers concurrently. The code is a bit buggy here and there, and I believe because of that, some times I see that instead of 1+, HAProxy assigns `server_id` as `0` (in my configured stick table for persisted sessions) to the incoming connection which obviously results in a 502 error.

I tried finding in docs on that behavior, but there isn't any information, does anyone has any idea why/when is that?